# Does cokkie path matter for deleting cookie

Tags: django, http, cookies

I have a cookie:

```
Name: trace
Value: True
Path: /
Expires: until of browser session end
```

I send a response from django server with a cookie I set this way:
`response.set_cookie('trace', max_age=0, path=/some/path/)`. I suppose this way will make browser to delete cookie.

The question is: should it affect initial cookie with `path=/`? Or if the path is different, initial cookie should stay alive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it will not affect a cookie with a different path. The name and path are both checked to see if a cookie matches.

Same thing happens when you set a new value to a cookie on a particular path. It will not affect other cookies with the same name and different paths than the one you set.